# ¿Cómo evitar el error de .addEventListener no es una función?

Tags: javascript, html5

En mi `index.html` ya tengo cargado todo lo que quiero mostrar y quiero implementar un "carrito de compras" sin embargo, en consola se muestra el error de que la función `loadEventL()` no es en sí una función a pesar de que en el javascript si está definida como tal.

código javascript:

```
let allContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('MS-content');

loadEventL();

function loadEventL() {
    allContainer.addEventListener('click', agregar);
}

function agregar(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

código en html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">

<head>
   <title>Prueba</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <?php require('./layout/head.php') ?>
   <script src="JS/multislider.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <?php require('header.php) ?>
   <div class="MS-content">
      <h1>Categoria 1</h1>
      <div class="item">
        <h2>Nombre</h2>
        <img src="coming.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h2>Nombre</h2>
        <img src="coming.jpg">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="MS-content">
      <h1>Categoria 2</h1>
      <div class="item">
        <h2>Nombre</h2>
        <img src="coming.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h2>Nombre</h2>
        <img src="coming.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h2>Nombre</h2>
        <img src="coming.jpg">
      </div>
   </div>
   <?php require('./layout/vCarrito.php') ?>
   <script>
      var cachebuster = Math.random(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
      document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="JS/carrito.js?cb=' + cachebuster + '" ></scr' + 'ipt>' );
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Como pueden notar hago llamados con el `require(...)` ya que son elementos que se van a repetir en varios archivos de html y los tengo creados en archivos separados con el fin de que si necesito hacer cambios solo se los hace en un lugar y también por temas de capacidad del proyecto; unos archivos son la hoja de estilo, ventanas modales, scripts, etc.

No tengo entendido bien que es lo que falla para que me de ese resultado, y por lo que he consultado si tengo bien organizado el html y si tengo ubicado el llamado al script luego de todo lo relacionado al html y no creo que haya inconvenientes ya que estoy usando un cachebuster por temas de visualización de cambios.

**Talvez alguien ha tenido algún caso similar que me pueda ayudar a comprender que estaría mal**

**Nota:** Utilizo el `getElementsByClassName('MS-content)` ya que en otros archivos con extensión html tengo otros ` y por lo que tengo entendido es mejor utilizar esto envés del `querySelectorAll()` ya que cuando se ejecuta solo lee los div que ya se cargan en el DOM y si se abre otro sitio que igual tiene esa clase ya no la agrega al NodeList que  devuelve el método.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El fallo está en que tratas a `allContainer` como si fuera un solo objeto, cuando es un array de objetos porque es lo que devuelve la función `getElementsByClassName()` según su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

> Retorna un objecto similar a un array de los elementos hijos que
> tengan todos los nombres de clase indicados.

La solución pasa por recorrerlo adecuadamente en un bucle:

```javascript
function loadEventL() {
  for(i=0; i<allContainer.length; i++) {
    allContainer[i].addEventListener('click', agregar);
  }
}
```

Ya nos diras si te ha funcionado.

Comment: Si me funciono, gracias @masterguru

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro. Si esta respuesta satisface a tu pregunta, recuerda aceptarla para que el resto de la comunidad lo sepa, gracias. En este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) explican como aceptar las respuestas válidas, y en este otro [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) el porque es importante hacerlo para el buen funcionamiento del sitio.